# doctrine:generate:entities --generate-methods remove annotaions

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

i am generating entities from database using this command

```
php artisan doctrine:mapping:import annotation
```

and than using this command to generate methods

```
php artisan doctrine:generate:entities --generate-methods
```

It generates methods correctly but remove details from the entities

```
  /**
 * Users
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="users_email_unique", columns={"email"})})

 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
```

this is when is ran first command, and that is correct form of the entity
but when i ran the next command it remove the details and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Users
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;
```

how can i configure laravel to not remove the extra details when generating methods. Or should i go with what is generated somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `--generate-annotations` flag

```
php artisan doctrine:generate:entities --generate-methods --generate-annotations
```